# Android - Overlayservice, pass click-event to child object

Tags: android, onclick, parameter-passing, overlay

I've implemented an overlayservice in my android application, and it should pass the click-event onto the next child below it... Lets say for instance a button
Any idea of how to do this? I've tried to set the click to false so in theory it should pass the click onto the next child, but it just dosen't seems to work..

```
overlayView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsF = params;
        private int initialX;
        private int initialY;
        private float initialTouchX;
        private float initialTouchY;

        @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                // Get current time in nano seconds.

                initialX = paramsF.x;
                initialY = paramsF.y;
                initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                paramsF.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                windowManager.updateViewLayout(overlayView, paramsF);
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: I must say - it smells like malware code. Can you please elaborate on your use case? why is the button hidden below your own stuff?

Comment: So the usecase is that I have an overlay service (pointer/cursor) which shows where in the application you are. And when you click on the screen should should not click on the overlay object but instead of the underlying one (passing the click to the child)